# Encrypt & Decrypt , OpenSSL , PBKDF2

Tags: php, encryption

I have put together this basic Encryption and Decryption script

I was wondering if someone could review this and tell me if there is anything I have done wrong or possible improvements.

I was also curious if someone could answer for example if someone was to gain access to the stored information `salt|IV|tag|cipher|cipherText` how easy/difficult it would be for someone to figure out the encrypted data.

I really appreciate any feedback and am just looking to improve this in anyway or recognize any mistakes.

I have to admit I had not heard of [openssl_pbkdf2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pbkdf2.php) and [openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) before today. So any information or recommendations welcome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Encryption & Decryption Method</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=ds28j2mdw0_encryption;host=localhost:3306';
$user = 'jds8e2ksdsD';
$password = 'Ot3ce4_9';

try {

   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
exit;
}

if($_POST['Encrypt'] != ''){
    
$key = $_POST['encryptionPassword'];

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12);
$keyLength = 40;
$iterations = 10000;
$generated_key = openssl_pbkdf2($key, $salt, $keyLength, $iterations, 'sha256');

$plaintext = $_POST['baseData'];
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $generated_key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo "Cipher Text: " . $ciphertext . "<br>";
    $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `encryptedData` (`IV`,`cipherText`,`cipher`,`tag`,`salt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $insert->bindParam(1,base64_encode($iv), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(2,$ciphertext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(3,base64_encode($cipher), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(4,base64_encode($tag), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->bindParam(5,base64_encode($salt), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert->execute();
}
    echo 'encrypt form posted';
}

if($_POST['Decrypt'] != ''){
    
    $inputPassword = $_POST['encryptionPassword'];
    
    $inputCipher = $_POST['encryptedData'];
    
    $select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `encryptedData` WHERE `cipherText` = '$inputCipher'");
    $select->execute();
    $fetch = $select->fetch();
    
    $salt = base64_decode($fetch['salt']);
    $keyLength = 40;
    $iterations = 10000;
    $generated_key = openssl_pbkdf2($inputPassword, $salt, $keyLength, $iterations, 'sha256');

    $iv = base64_decode($fetch['IV']);
    $tag = base64_decode($fetch['tag']);
    $cipher = base64_decode($fetch['cipher']);
    
    
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{

    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($inputCipher, $cipher, $generated_key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo "Original Text: " . $original_plaintext . "<br>";
}
    echo 'decrypt form posted';
}


?>

<h3>Encrypt</h3>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="baseData" placeholder="baseData" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="encryptionPassword" placeholder="encryptionPassword" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="Encrypt" value="Encrypt"/>
</form>

<h3>Decrypt</h3>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="encryptedData" placeholder="encryptedData" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="encryptionPassword" placeholder="encryptionPassword" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="Decrypt" value="Decrypt"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be easier for subsequent readers to understand if you had not deleted the old question and simply added the new information. Also, a code review is off topic, there are dedicated sites for that, e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Topaco I agree I am glad you found the question again, I did want to know your feedback, Have I used the `pbkdf2` and `encrypt` correctly though?

Comment: Is the code not working? Please describe the problem.

Comment: aes-128-gcm uses a 16 bytes key and not a 40 bytes key (PHP simply truncates the rest). Binary data (salt, iv, ciphertext, tag) must be stored in binary or with a suitable binary-to-text-encoding otherwise the data will be corrupted.

Comment: the code is working ; I am just curious if I can do anything more

Comment: @Topaco what would I need to change to increase from 16 to 40 byte keys? and how do I store the `salt|iv|ciphertext|tag` in binary ? I guess im currently not storing in Binary as the database showing random characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235484/discussion-between-topaco-and-lewis).

Comment: What does `$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);` end up with? 12 I hope?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's correct 12

Comment: OK, then they have designed that call correctly, perfect. Just checking. Note that besides getting to large a key size, asking more than the output size of the configured hash (32 bytes for SHA-256) from PBKDF2 only the machine of the user.

Comment: ... only taxes the machine of the user: the attacker often doesn't need to calculate as much per try, is what I meant to say.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/79855#79855